# Check definition-Decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the following math definition of a decreasing sequence from a certain range correct?

$\exists n_0. !n. n \ge n_0 \Rightarrow f(n+1) <= f(n)$

I mean by "from a certain range", that when $n \ge$ a given range (here $n_0$), the sequence starts to be decreasing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems with it:

1. You quantify $n_0$ but then you don't use it in the consequent ($n_0$ should come after the arrow somehow).
2. I think there is some notational error after the existence sign (what is the period and the exclamation point doing there?)
3. People use different terminology, so you may want to include the verbal definition of "decreasing sequences from a certain range".